# How can I cast video from my iOS app on Android TV on same WI-Fi connection?

Tags: ios, swift, video, casting, avplayer

I'm using SWIFT 5, UIKit and Xcode 12.4

I'm using `AVPlayerViewController` and `AVPlayer` to play videos in my app that are from the AWS server. I want to cast videos from my app on my Android TV which are on the same Wi-Fi connection. The same I can do that in other apps like `YouTube` on my iPhone XR. When I open YouTube and click the broadcast icon it shows the list of devices on the same internet connection. I want to list devices and cast video from my app to those devices.

I checked the *Miracast* SDK but it is for screen mirroring, I don't want that. Also, there is a library that supports Android apps called `Exoplayer` but is not available in SWIFT.

Questions:

1. How can I achieve this? Do I need to install a third party(which one)?
2. I set `allowsExternalPlayback` to `true` to play video using Airplay on Apple TV and it's not working. How can I airplay video as well on Apple TV?

Any recommendation for a third-party library? Or any sample example?

Comment: See Help Desk to find out what type of questions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with usin Airplay. Check this official Apple video from WWDC : [video link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/509/)